# Can anybody can help me with a Rewrite API in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to rewrite a URL form WP. I use this:

```
add_rewrite_rule( ‘property-for-sale([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$’, ‘archive-property-for-sale.php?areas=$matches[1]&price=$matches[2]′, ‘top’);
```

i want to rewrite the url from `/wordpress/property-for-sale/?area=any&price=1000000/` to `/wordpress/property-for-sale/any/1000000/`

`property-for-sale` and `area` are made with `Types( Custom Fields)` with `taxonomy`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works anything like preg_replace which it probably does then the following will help you.

```
preg_match_all('~/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\??area=([^&]+)?&price=([^&]+)/~',"/wordpress/property-for-sale/?area=any&price=1000000/",$m);
print_r($m);
echo preg_replace('~/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\??area=([^&]+)?&price=([^&]+)/~','/$1/$2/$3/$4/',"/wordpress/property-for-sale/?area=any&price=1000000/");
```

Comment: i get 404 erorr and this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /wordpress/property-for-sale/?area=any&price=1000000/ ) [1] => Array ( [0] => wordpress ) [2] => Array ( [0] => property-for-sale ) [3] => Array ( [0] => any ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1000000 ) ) /wordpress/property-for-sale/any/1000000/

Comment: Yes, thats the captured array. Use the pattern i gave you on your function dont just paste that somewhere, and replace $1 with $matches[1] and so on.

Comment: i put it on my Rewrite API that is installed in plugins.